# Using LIKE % in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, hsqldb

How do I use `LIKE %` in Hibernate. I want to use a SQL with `LIKE %` in my `hbm.xml` file. I have 2 queries which I am consolidating to 1.

**The query looks like this:**

```
select * from PAY_GROUP_VW where CASE_SID=? AND CASE_TLE like %?%
```

I also tried `%?%`. I have used like clause without `%` and it works. But `%` does not work.

**Wrapped exception:**

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:630)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:424)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeFind(HibernateTemplate.java:343)
```

**This is how I pass the parameters:**

```
q.setParameter(0, csId);
q.setParameter(1, csTle);
return q.list();
```

**Tried like `%` || `?` and got the following exception:**

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:630)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:424)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeFind(HibernateTemplate.java:343)
```

Comment: Can you put your query with your code or configuration in hbm.xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the user_id is not a char/varchar? You have to convert the user_id with str() to character data first!

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM abc.def_vw a
WHERE user_id = ?
AND str(user_id) LIKE '%' || ?
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `LIKE '%?%'` and second parameter string to make the query. The field also should be a string type because `like` is used to compare strings.

Answer (score 0):

3 things to notice:

- Is user_id string?
- like in HQL works fine. for example like '%something%'
- Your query doesn't make sense "where user_id =? and user_id like '%'" what are you trying to do ? Use only one of the conditions.